# Update multiple entities in MVC4 with LINQ, SQLquery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to update/remove multiples entities, for example

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("removeresponsible")]
public ActionResult removeresponsibleaction(Responsible modelo)
{
    Responsible responsible = db.Responsibles.Single(x => x.responsible_id == modelo.responsible_id);
    db.Responsibles.Remove(responsible);
    db.SaveChanges();
    ViewBag.responsible = db.Responsibles.ToList();
    return View("responsiblemanager");
}
```

This code works with one single responsible with an unique id, but how can I do it if there are many responsible with the same id? For example, I know that with SQL it would be something like this "delete from table where responsible_id=3".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Entity Framework 6` you can use [`RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220170(v=vs.113).aspx) method:

```
var responsibles = db.Responsibles.Where(x => x.responsible_id == modelo.responsible_id).ToList();
db.Responsibles.RemoveRange(responsibles);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quickly answer, i tried it and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using EF 6, you will have to loop through your list of models, and delete each one separately.

e.g.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("removeresponsible")]
public ActionResult removeresponsibleaction(IEnumerable<Responsible> models)
{
    foreach(var model in models)
    {
        Responsible responsible = db.Responsibles.Single(x => x.responsible_id == model.responsible_id);
        db.Responsibles.Remove(responsible);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    ViewBag.responsible = db.Responsibles.ToList();
    return View("responsiblemanager");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried it on EF 5.0.0.0 too and worked, it's easier in EF 6 but it's also helpful to know how to when there is no access to EF 6